# Cmake unknown command

Tags: cmake

```
cmake version 3.7.2
```

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (INCLUDE_SUBDIRECTORY):
  Unknown CMake command "INCLUDE_SUBDIRECTORY".


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

../CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.7)
# allow more human readable "if then else" constructs
#SET( CMAKE_ALLOW_LOOSE_LOOP_CONSTRUCTS TRUE )
# Add the local Find*.cmake scripts
LIST (APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules)

PROJECT( CellSearch )
ENABLE_TESTING()
```

Answer (score 1):

When compiling `OpenUSRP` you need to add `INCLUDE_SUBDIRECTORY(OpenUSRP)` in `uhd/host/lib/usrp/CMakeLists.txt` but instead you are adding it to `OpenUSRP/CMakeLists.txt`. It's also important to clone OpenUSRP inside the `uhd/host/lib/usrp/` directory.

Execute all commands exactly as described in https://github.com/jocover/OpenUSRP#libuhd-mode or https://github.com/jocover/OpenUSRP/blob/6f6028c30161f1ce63222722b0da8e6d68b203af/.travis.yml#L50-L60

I've posted a reply in https://github.com/jocover/OpenUSRP/issues/12 as well

When compiling `LTE-Cell-Scanner` you should not do any such modifications. I've posted a reply in https://github.com/JiaoXianjun/LTE-Cell-Scanner/issues/29